# Undefined function or variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a problem running my main function in MATLAB (the main program and calls other functions). Trying to run it gives me the error "??? Undefined function or variable 'max_x_address'". But, as you can see below, it has been declared as a global. This is really bothering me, so any help would be appreciated. (Do I have to modify my pathdef.m file? That is what the MATLAB troubleshooting says, but I followed some of the steps and it didn't help.)
The following is a skeleton of the program:

```
function Adaptive_Information
global HUBS, max_x_address, max_y_address;
.
.
max_x_address = 10;
.
.
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare it global in every context that will use it.  That is, add:

```
global max_x_address
```

To the beginning of each function which will use `max_x_address`, plus the base workspace (if needed).

Comment: Thanks, although I was able to fix it. The solution turned out to be to avoid declaring multiple variables on the same line. (Strange behavior from MATLAB)

Answer (score 2):

Actually the line

```
global HUBS, max_x_address, max_y_address;
```

does not declare three global variables. The comma is a statement or expression delimiter in Matlab as is the EOL or the semicolon. So Matlab reads the above as

```
global HUBS
max_x_address
max_y_address;
```

So what it does is to declare `HUBS` as global. Then it tries to retrieve the value of `max_x_address` and print it. Finally it would retrieve the value of `max_y_address` and throw it away.

The correct syntax to declare more than one global variable is to delimit them by spaces (see also the documentation):

global HUBS max_x_address max_y_address